# Multiple duplicates finding

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
ticket_id   destination
---------   -----------
5           Paris
5           Paris
5           California
5           Paris
6           Nebraska
15          London
6           Nebraska
6           Nebraska
```

I would like to select all ticket ids that are in the table over 2 times and are to the same destination.

So, in this case, I would obtain a table like:

```
ticket_id   destination num_times
---------   ----------- ---------
5           Paris       3
6           Nebraska    3
```

I know how to obtain all tickets that are repeated certain times:

```
SELECT ticket_id, destination,
COUNT(ticket_id) AS num_times
FROM table
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 2 )
```

However I am not sure how I can add the destination similarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just group by both ticket id and destination:

```
SELECT ticket_id, destination,
 COUNT(ticket_id) AS num_times
FROM table
GROUP BY ticket_id, destination
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, your query doesn't need to be quite so big. Here's a briefer version that works:

```
SELECT ticket_id, destination, COUNT(*) AS num_times
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Mantra: `LESS == GOOD`

Comment: Mantra: try to avoid positional field references and use explicit fields names instead ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I've been doing this for 20+ years, and using positional references has *never* caused a problem. Mainly, it's a lot easier to read (especially with a large number of non-aggregate columns), and you don't have to repeat calculations (if your non-aggregate columns are calculated)